# Ruby on Rails: listing Products with belongs_to / has_many assosiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I am trying to built RoR app with Users, Rooms, Products.
I'll begin by listing my models below.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :name, :user_id, presence: true
 validates :price, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :rooms, through: :memberships
 <...>
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :memberships
 has_many :users, through: :memberships
 validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 6..20 }
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :room
 validates :user_id, presence: true
 validates :room_id, presence: true
end
```

Users can have many Products, they can join/leave Rooms.

I my views I want to show current_user's Room (which has multiple Users who have multiple Products) and list all Products by all Users who are in that Room (and sort by created_at DESC). Could you help me to find a good way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There are 100's of tutorials on the web showing how to do this, please look one of them up and if you have a specific question you're welcome to post that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use eager_load to load the model associations. This is good starting [guide](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiih8LLk7rRAhWLgI8KHbr7C0oQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.arkency.com%2F2013%2F12%2Frails4-preloading%2F&usg=AFQjCNH7iwGlmQtHevGkWGWcCYTlOFBDPg&sig2=j8mzOlZrp4j0LIaFuwYm_g) to understand eager_load, includes and joins and their differences.

Now you use following query for your usecase.

```
result = current_user.eager_load(:rooms => [:users => :products ]).order("rooms.created_at DESC")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems that it is what I was looking for. Thank you for the sggestion. I am looking into eager_load now.

Comment: i am glad it worked for you, please accept this answer.